# SMTP Fallback relay server explanation

Tags: linux, postfix, redhat

I am using postfix on Linux redhat server,

I can't understand the functionality of smtp fallback relay configured in both main.cf & master.cf

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `smtp_fallback_relay` parameter is there to allow you to extend the time or amount of attempts to deliver to external hosts, especially in cases where you would fill up the local outbound queue with messages (primarily host not found, or host unavailable messages). If you have a 24 hour retry period, you would send it to the fallback relay so it could continue to make delivery attempts until its timeout is reached. This can be useful in situations where you have to send large amounts of email to large providers, as they often do not accept more than a certain amount of mail per hour from single hosts.

Comment: MAke sense thanks alot, But how can i add another ip to relayhost in main.cf so that i can avoid single point of failure of relayhost?

Comment: You can add multiple `smtp_fallback_relay` hosts as the documentation says: `The fallback relays must be SMTP destinations. Specify a domain, host, host:port, [host]:port, [address] or [address]:port; the form [host] turns off MX lookups. If you specify multiple SMTP destinations, Postfix will try them in the specified order.`

Comment: If however you want multiple relay hosts there are multiple methods to add these, the easiest would be to specify `relayhost = domain.name`, in that manner, Postfix will do an MX lookup on that domain, and will normally return multiple MX records.

Comment: Thank you very much, so i can add relayhosts in the following format relayhost = ip1, ip2 ? .. how will smtp use ip2 ? will this happen when there are massive number of mails or only when ip1 crashed.

Comment: No, the `smtp_fallback_relay` permits multiple destinations, you can only hard code 1 address into `relayhost`, unless you want to set up sender dependent or destination dependent relays (read about them in the postfix documentation). I suggest using just the domain name in the relayhost parameter. If you want to see how many servers it can chose from, run this command `dig -t mx gmail.com`.